# Getting an error EOF : Command no found when using ssh

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, sh, scp

I am trying to rename the filenames in remote server like filename-dirname.suffix
and copy the files to my server  .
I had written code like ....

```
  #!/usr/bin/bash
  TRANSFERSERVERXMLS="/emp/transfer/XMLS"
  REMOTESERVERXMLS="remoteemp/empdir/XMLS"

  # renaming the filenames in remote server like filename-dirname.suffix  
  ssh abc@xyz REMOTESERVERXMLS=$REMOTESERVERXMLS 'bash -s'<< 'EOF'

  for i in $REMOTESERVERXMLS/* ; do 
     if [[ -d $i ]]; then
            dirname=$(basename $i)
                     for j in $REMOTESERVERXMLS/$dirname/* ; do

                               fname="$(basename "$j")"

                               prefix=$(echo $fname | awk -F "." 'NF{NF-=1};1')
                               suffix=$(echo $fname | awk -F "." '{print $NF}')

                               target=$prefix-$dirname.$suffix

                                mv $REMOTESERVERXMLS/$dirname/"$fname" $REMOTESERVERXMLS/$dirname/"${target// /_}"
                          done
    fi
  done
  EOF
 scp abc@xyz:${REMOTESERVERXMLS}/*/* ${TRANSFERSERVERXMLS}
```

Getting an error : EOF:Command not found 
and scp is not working ( not able to copy into calling server)

Comment: BTW, consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ (you'll want to pass the code inside the heredoc through separately, since from the perspective of the outer script it's just a string literal).

Comment: ...the other problem you have besides the heredoc is the dependency on environment variables being passed through, but we have other Q&A entries with answers describing how to reliably pass variables over ssh. (`printf -v transferservenrxmls_q %q "$transferserverxmls"`, and then `"bash -s $transferserverxmls"` will make that value `$1` from the context of the remote script... if we know the remote user's default interpreter to be bash; otherwise, things get a little stickier).

Comment: ...btw, note the use of a lower-case variable name there -- see fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Answer (score 7):

You have a space before the delimiter `EOF`.  Do not indent `EOF` at the end of your "here document". The delimiter (`EOF`) must be the only thing on the line, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

Alternatively use `<<- 'EOF'` and indent with a tab.

Comment: The OP also has some problems in that they're expecting environment variables to be transmitted over ssh, but this *is* the issue at the root of the question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: to be honest when I saw the title I knew what it would be, I didn't look at the rest of it!  I thought it would be a duplicate, but I'm still looking.